# Upon compiling opencv, the pi is reporting that it is out of space

Tags: raspbian

Ok, i have an 8 gig micro SD, I've been going through the process of installing open CV on the pi, however for whatever reason, the pi runs out of space upon compiling open CV, I'm on Windows, so can anyone help me out? i understand that there is partitions that Windows cant detect, but is still need to figure this out.

Comment: Does this help? http://answers.opencv.org/question/78820/opencv-python-raspberry-pi-minimum-required-size-on-disk/

Comment: *"i understand that there is partitions that Windows cant detect"* ->
Yes, and if you expanded the root fs to fill an 8 GB card, the one it *can* detect will account for **< 1% of the total**, ~60 MB.  So if you blithely tried to compile or install openCV there it would not get you very far.  However that seems unlikely.  If Varad's answer or stevieb's comment isn't the issue, you should explain exactly what you did and what you mean by "runs out of space".

Comment: @Mike I've locked this question because your edit along the lines of "Okay, sorry silly me, just ignore this" amounts to defacing the post when in fact it's one of the comments here (the first one above, about the large amount of space required to compile openCV) that led you to this conclusion.  For future reference, if you have this kind of realization, simply add an answer of your own and it may save someone else some time in the future, whereas a question whose title has been changed to "ignore this" isn't likely to help anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the command disk free (df) and find the available space in root

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ESP8266 $ df -lk
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       28353172 6080752  20809100  23% /
```

In this case I have a 32 Gb card which has 28 Gb of space and I have 20 Gb available. Check the same in your case as well.

If the space is less than the actual card size then you need to expand the file system.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ESP8266 $ sudo raspi-config
```

[image]

If your file system is already expanded you are likely to get a message like below

[image]

Comment: nope, sorry, sometimes you overlook the small things, my sd was too full, i didn't anticipate that the installation would take more than 8 gig, that's my fault

Comment: @MikePerreman Yeah but that first step whould have cleared your issue and that's why I told you to use df -lk and check the available space and used up space. Anyways I believed the answer still had your needed solution but on the very first step. :) Good Mike have a good rest of the day.